# Need to write months in a sequential order

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

I have a list of columns with Month/Year as title (like JAN09, FEB09, AUG10). I have to check if the months are sequentially aligned. if not then align it and if a specific month is not available then create a column name title as the month name and go ahead. I have written a code but it works for the first year (like from year 09-11, it will identify all the months of 09 but after that it fails to identify and creates a new month every time even if it is present).

```
Sub MonthFinder()
    Dim montharray As Variant

    montharray = Array("JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC")

    lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 5
    lastcol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    minmonth = Right(Cells(5, 2), 2)
    range0 = 2
    maxmonth = Right(Cells(5, 2), 2)

    Do Until range0 > lastcol
        If Right(Cells(5, range0), 2) < minmonth Then
            minmonth = Right(Cells(5, range0), 2)
        End If

        If Right(Cells(5, range0), 2) > maxmonth Then
            maxmonth = Right(Cells(5, range0), 2)
        End If
        range0 = range0 + 1
    Loop

    minsortmonth = minmonth
    maxsortmonth = maxmonth

    place = 2

    Do Until minsortmonth = maxsortmonth + 1
        arraycount = 0

        Do Until arraycount = 12
            range1 = 2
            lastcol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

            Do Until Left(Cells(5, range1), 3) = montharray(arraycount) And Right(Cells(5, range1), 2) = minsortmonth Or range1 > lastcol
                range1 = range1 + 1
            Loop

            If range1 > lastcol Then
                Range(Cells(5, place), Cells(lastrow, place)).Select
                Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                Cells(5, place).Value = montharray(arraycount) & minsortmonth
            Else
                If range1 <> place Then
                    Range(Cells(5, range1), Cells(lastrow, range1)).Cut
                    Cells(5, place).Select
                    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                End If
            End If
            arraycount = arraycount + 1
            place = place + 1
        Loop

        minsortmonth = minsortmonth + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of having the textual value "JAN09", "FEB09", etc. in each cell, have you considered actually storing a date-value in each cell, "2009-01-01", "2009-02-01", etc. and then simply format the cells as MMMYY? This would make it much easier to order the columns correctly.

Comment: Yes, but the data comes in the same format so it will be more hectic to extract the data and change that to date format.

Comment: What *exactly* does this data look like? I tried to recreate this in a spreadhseet and Excel automatically converts "JAN09" to a date ...

Comment: The pseudo-dates can easily be converted to real dates with `=DATEVALUE("01"&A1)` or in VBA with a loop using something like `Cells(x, y) = DateValue("01" & Cells(x, y).Value)`.

Comment: Perhaps you can use a Date variable and start from the first cell, then add a month to it using `dDate = DateAdd("m",1,[StartDate])`, a second variable to format it `sDate = UCase(Format(dDate,"MMMYY"))` then compare the values in cell. If it doesn't match then add cell (shift right) and insert sDate to it.

Comment: If you could include some comments in the code to break down what logic you are using, it will read easier.  I'm not having the easiest time following it just to look it over.  The ranges and loops are a bit confusing to just glance at without seeing your sheet

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to change the logic you do and to use [Dictionary](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/187234?wa=wsignin1.0).

Let's say your data (columns) are initially sorted as follow: **JAN09, FEB09, APR09...MAR00, MAY00, JUL00, ...**, etc. There are some gaps in months collection and you want to fill in missing months. Here is an idea:

```
'Note: columns are initially sorted!
Sub CheckMonthSequence()
Dim dic As Dictionary
Dim element As Variant
Dim col As Integer, pos As Integer, rng As Range
Dim initialDate As Date, endDate As Date, sTmp As String

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
'define initial date as January of ...
sTmp = rng
sTmp = "01/01/" & "20" & Right(sTmp, 2)
initialDate = CDate(sTmp)
'define end date
sTmp = rng.End(xlToRight)
sTmp = Left(sTmp, 3) & "/01/" & "20" & Right(sTmp, 2)
endDate = CDate(sTmp)

'create new dictionary with collection of months
Set dic = GetMonthsAsDictionary(initialDate, endDate)
'define a range of columns to sort and update
col = 0
Do While rng.Offset(, col) <> ""
    element = rng.Offset(, col)
    If dic.Exists(element) Then
        pos = dic.Item(element)
        If pos > col Then
            Do While col < pos
                rng.Offset(, col).EntireColumn.Insert xlShiftToRight
                'sometimes it loses the reference, so...
                Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
                rng.Offset(, col) = GetKeyByIndex(dic, col)
                col = col + 1
            Loop
            col = pos
        End If
    End If
    col = col + 1
Loop


End Sub


'needs reference to MS Scripting Runtime
Function GetMonthsAsDictionary(ByVal StartingMonth As Date, EndMonth As Date) As Dictionary
Dim dic As Dictionary
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

'create new dictionary
Set dic = New Dictionary
i = 0
j = DateDiff("M", StartingMonth, EndMonth)
For i = 0 To j
    dic.Add UCase(Format(DateAdd("M", i, StartingMonth), "MMMyy")), i
    Debug.Print UCase(Format(DateAdd("M", i, StartingMonth), "MMMyy")), i
Next

Set GetMonthsAsDictionary = dic

End Function

Function GetKeyByIndex(ByVal dic As Dictionary, ByVal ind As Integer) As String
Dim dic_Keys As Variant, element As Variant

dic_Keys = dic.keys
For Each element In dic_Keys
    If dic.Item(element) = ind Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next

GetKeyByIndex = element

End Function
```

As you can see, above code:
1) create dictionary which contains months and corrensponding index.
2) loops through the collection of columns
3) checks that value corresponds to index in a dictionary
4) fill in header when it's necessary.

I know, it's not perfect, but good point to start.

Cheers
Maciej

**[EDIT]**

Using your logic, the code might look like:

```
Option Explicit 'do not apply initialize variable without its declaration

Sub MonthFinder()
Dim montharray As Variant, rng As Range
Dim firstyear As Integer, lastyear As Integer, curryear As Integer
Dim curroffset As Integer, lastcol As Integer, currmonth As Integer

curroffset = 0
montharray = Array("JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC")

'start here:
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
'first year
firstyear = CInt(Right(rng, 2))
'fid last col
lastcol = rng.End(xlToRight).Column - rng.Column
'find last year
lastyear = CInt(Right(rng.Offset(ColumnOffset:=lastcol), 2))

For curryear = firstyear To lastyear
    For currmonth = LBound(montharray) To UBound(montharray)
        'if current month is equal to last month - exit for
        If CStr(montharray(currmonth) & curryear) = CStr(rng.End(xlToRight)) Then Exit For
        'month is proper - do nothing
        If rng.Offset(ColumnOffset:=curroffset) = CStr(montharray(currmonth) & curryear) Then GoTo SkipMonth
        'other cases
        rng.Offset(ColumnOffset:=curroffset).EntireColumn.Insert xlShiftToRight
        Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
        rng.Offset(ColumnOffset:=curroffset) = CStr(montharray(currmonth) & curryear)
SkipMonth:
        curroffset = curroffset + 1
    Next
Next

Set rng = Nothing

End Sub
```

Cheers,
Maciej

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I will surely apply it but my question is why my code was running for first year but not for next and so on. it reads the text perfectly for first year but fails to read for next year and prepares a new one. May be for future reference I need to know where I am going wrong.

Comment: @atulhandoo, Please share dummy data (workbook). I'll check it and try to answer your question.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4d7he5EA_C0Q2tyMEVrcXE3RGM/view?usp=sharing

Please check if you are able to access. This is the file which I was working on. You will find my actual code in there. Here the columns are mar10, jun11, jun12..... that means we need months from jan-dec 10, jan-dec 11, jan-dec 12. Thanks

Comment: I changed the code to your needs. Please, see updated answer. Run ChekMonthSequence procedure. Updated file is avaliable here: http://losmac.republika.pl/download/checkmonthsequence.7z

Comment: Working Good. Thanks a lot. :)